# ProgressBar в отдельном потоке

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли сделать ProgressBar как-то в отдельном потоке? Дело в том, что когда у меня из ArrayList рисуются маркеры в большом количестве на гугловскую карту, то тормозится основной поток и бегунок ProgressBar перестает крутиться на время..

Код загрузки маркеров на карту:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < myPoints.size(); i++) {

        String i_var_0 = myPoints.get(i)[0];
        String i_var_1 = myPoints.get(i)[1];
        String i_var_2 = myPoints.get(i)[2];
        String i_var_3 = myPoints.get(i)[3];

                int resourceId = mapsActivity.getResources().getIdentifier(i_var_0, "drawable", mapsActivity.getPackageName());
                List_Markers_Normal.add(
                mapsActivity.mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(i_var_2), Double.parseDouble(i_var_3))).zIndex(999).icon(
                        BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(resourceId)).title(i_var_1)) );

    }
```

Прогрессбар пока просто крутится поверх всего..

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/circleProgressBar_15"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

`ProgressBar`, как UI элемент, должен работать в UI потоке.
А чтобы решить проблему, нужно вашу трудоемкую задачу спрятать в отдельный поток. Примерно рабочий код:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        // ваша тяжелая задача
        for (int i = 0; i < myPoints.size(); i++) {
            String i_var_0 = myPoints.get(i)[0];
            String i_var_1 = myPoints.get(i)[1];
            String i_var_2 = myPoints.get(i)[2];
            String i_var_3 = myPoints.get(i)[3];

            int resourceId = mapsActivity.getResources().getIdentifier(i_var_0, "drawable", mapsActivity.getPackageName());
            final Тип marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(i_var_2), Double.parseDouble(i_var_3))).zIndex(999).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(resourceId)).title(i_var_1));
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                // работаем с UI после выполнения тяжелой задачи..... тут вставка маркера
            }
        });
    }
}).start();
```

С использованием Kotlin корутин все проще:

```
launch(UI) {
    async(CommonPool) {
        // тяжелая задача
    }.await()
    // работаем с UI
}
```

Comment: Я как не пробовал, не получается.. Можете привести пример? Тут пока рисуются маркеры на карте, то ProgressBar останавливается.. Как спрятать отрисовку маркеров на карте в отдельный поток? Я вот так делал:

Comment: runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                              @Override
                              public void run() {
                    int resourceId = mapsActivity.getResources().getIdentifier(i_var_0, "drawable", mapsActivity.getPackageName());
                    List_Markers_Normal.add(
                    mapsActivity.mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(i_), Double.parseDouble(i_var_3))).zIndex(999).icon(
                            BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(resourceId)).title(finalI_var_)) );
                }
            });

Comment: @Alex455, `runOnUiThread` запускает код в ui потоке, что по сути не меняет причину вашей проблемы. чтобы не было зависаний нужно запускать код не в ui потоке а в новом, своем

Comment: Я так понял что это невозможно сделать? Чтобы и ProgressBar  крутился и чтобы маркеры отрисовывались в это время на карте?

Comment: вот сейчас гляньте код

Comment: new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable()  подчеркивает красным в андроид студии.. Если его убрать вовсе, то все равно бегунок прогрессбара зависает..

Comment: Может отрисовка маркеров на гугл карте связанна с основным потоком, и поэтому его по любому тормозит? Если отобразить 500 маркеров на карте и начать карту двигать, то бегунок притормаживает.. По этому я и хотел чтобы он крутился отдельно в новом потоке, но видимо не получится..